# macro to produce special quote marks (e.g. /word/)

Tags: luatex, csquotes

I have a large text (> 300 pages) to edit in which words are often used as "word x" and not with their regular meaning. It is customary to mark such uses (often with ordinary quote marks or with /word/, e.g. the word "dog" or /cow/). 
I would like to mark the text for these uses and be flexible how they get typeset later. I think this can be achieved with a marco

```
\newcommand{\qword}[1]{/#1/}
```

but it would be more convenient if there were just a single command (e.g. "\qw") to apply to the next token or a begin-end combination (like "xxx" for ordinary quotes). 
Is this possible and how? I use luatex.

Comment: your question is not very clear, how do you want `\qw` to differ from `\qword`  perhaps it would be clearer if you showed a complete example paragraph using the desired markup, and describe the output you want from that paragraph.

Comment: I think `\qword{foo}` is already quite convenient. Do you want to be able to say `\qw foo\qw`? You could look into `csquotes`, amongst other features that package also offers active quotation marks.

Comment: You can just write `"dog"` in your document, and decide later to make every pair `".."` output `/../` or `\qword{..}` (and then define `\qword` as you wish). I think `\qw{dog}` is clean and simple enough to not seek alternatives, but if you want to just keep writting `"dog"` you can and still decide later if you want slashes or quotes or whatever.

Comment: thank you for the help - `\qword` is ineed convenient (when using the features of the editor to balance the `{..}.